# Indexing for later full text search in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, full-text-search

I am working on an application, where then need is to index the data without storing it to database.
When I initialize an abject it should index it. Consider there is a `pages` table with fields `page_title`, `tags`, `content`. 
The last field `content` may have a large amount of text data(some times in MBs). Which is not going to be used for processing at all.
My objective is to index that data without saving it to database. I mean only `pages`, `page_title`, `tags` will be saved into the DB and indexed as well, and `content` will be indexed only.

I am open to use any full-text search plugin/gem

Comment: Please let me know if any clarification is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented this using `ultrasphinx`. I am indexing by manually generating xml docs for sphinx.